# Is it possible to open another MacOS app in a Catalyst app

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, mac-catalyst

I tried using `NSWorkspace` but looks like it is not available in Catalyst. Following would build in MacOS but not in catalyst target.

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
     let appUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Applications/Preview.app")
     NSApplication.shared.openUrl(appUrl, options: [:]) { status in
     }
#else
     // launch PDFView in iOS
#endif
```

I get `'NSApplication' is unavailable in Mac Catalyst`.

Comment: With Mac Catalyst you're in UIKit land, not in AppKit land. So you must use UIApplication instead of NSApplication.

Comment: Maybe [this could be a solution](https://www.highcaffeinecontent.com/blog/20190607-Beyond-the-Checkbox-with-Catalyst-and-AppKit) for you? But it looks rather hack-ish.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `UIApplication.shared.open(url_to_application)`